Using spring-webmvc 6.1.3 in Spring Boot 2
The project was working fine until a moment when security check in our gitlab pipeline rejected a couple of spring dependencies during an update. One of them is spring-webmvc 5.3.39.
I searched for a version which has no vulnerabilities and is supported by Spring 2x. However, the last version compatible with Spring 2 is 5.3.39 which I'm currently using. To pass the security check, I anyways updated the spring-webmvc to 6.1.13. However, when I make API requests to any URL in my application, I just recieve 404 Not Found error.
The solution suggested by many was upgrading to Spring 3x. But, I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not, since the project was written in Java 8 many years ago and I'm also new to it.
I'm not sure what to do here
